# paste image on sms controller,iphone

Tags: iphone

Since MMS integration is not available on latest sdk.
I want to implement MMS in my app, what i am doing is , i am copying a image into pasteboard.
  UIPasteboard *pb = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
        [pb setImage:dataObj.images];
        NSLog(@"pb  %@", pb);

its getting copied into the pasteboard, but i am not able to paste it on sms controller's body.
controller.body = [pb setImage:dataObj.images]; // something like this

Please suggest me how can i paste it on sms controller's body.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can't, SMS is text only and so is the [`MFMessageComposeViewController`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/MessageUI/Reference/MFMessageComposeViewController_class/Reference/Reference.html).

Only the messages.app can send MMS, doing it from within your app you will only have SMS.